# Conditional based on file extension

Tags: conditionals, files

I have a piece of code whereby I adjust the output of a file depending on it's file extension:

```
{section_1_files}
  {section_1_files:file}
    {if {extension} == 'jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF'}
      <figure>
        <img src="{url}" alt="{section_1_files:label}" />
      </figure>
    {if:else}
      <div class="file">
        <a href="{url}">{section_1_files:label}</a>
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/section_1_files:file}
{/section_1_files}
```

However it doesn't seem to be working properly. If I add `{extension}` below the `{section_1_files:file}` line then `jpg` is displayed on the front end. The following code currently outputs this:

```
  <div class="file">
    <a href="http://domain.co.uk/uploads/test-image.jpg">Test image</a>
  </div>

  <div class="file">
    <a href="http://domain.co.uk/uploads/test-file.docx">Test file</a>
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Contains](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#contains-operator) and the [Concatenation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#string-concatenation-operator) operators to check if the file extension appears on the list:

```
{section_1_files}
  {section_1_files:file}
    {if "|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF|" *= "|" . extension . "|" }
      <figure>
        <img src="{url}" alt="{section_1_files:label}" />
      </figure>
    {if:else}
      <div class="file">
        <a href="{url}">{section_1_files:label}</a>
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/section_1_files:file}
{/section_1_files}
```

I don't have time now to check if the *contains operator* is case sensitive. If you could test it, please update this answer.

Why not to check for the [`{mime_type}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#string-concatenation-operator) using the [begins operator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#begins-with-operator)?

```
{section_1_files}
  {section_1_files:file}
    {if mime_type ^= "image/" }
      <figure>
        <img src="{url}" alt="{section_1_files:label}" />
      </figure>
    {if:else}
      <div class="file">
        <a href="{url}">{section_1_files:label}</a>
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/section_1_files:file}
{/section_1_files}
```

Comment: Both examples work perfectly. I've decided to go with the mime_type one as that looks a lot neater and will catch out anything I've missed (don't think I did though). Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 2):

change   `{if {extension} == 'jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF'}` to

```
{if section_1_files:extension== 'jpg' || section_1_files:extension=='JPG' ...
```